# mysql: list all tables with their columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a list of all tables followed by their columns of a database in mysql. For example if I have two tables Table1 and Table2 with their respective columns I want the output to something like this:

> Table1: col_1, col_2, col_3
>
> Table2: col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d

I have written this query todo so

```
select TABLE_NAME as tn, CONCAT_WS (', ', SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                                            from information_schema.columns 
                                            where TABLE_NAME = tn)
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'pgstudies'
order by table_name,ordinal_position;
```

When I run this code it returns an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns where
> TABLE_NAME = tn) from ' at line 1

Would you please let me know how to fix this error or present another method to obtain same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will do the trick.

```
SELECT table_name, GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position SEPARATOR ', ') as columns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'pgstudies'
GROUP BY table_name
ORDER BY table_name;
```